# python sqlite save multiple versions of the same table

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a .gdx file with 70 tables calculated from GAMS every week. Therefore every week, The report.gdx is converted to SQLite file as report.db for easier processing within other programming languages, namely R and Python.

The problem is, instead of having only the most updated version of the report.db, historical data also needs to be saved in the same database. Currently I have several report.db files of the same structure but different values.
One solution I could think of is to add extra column (Version ID) in every 70 tables and export it to a bigger database.

Or if there is any other way of attaching multiple version of the same database into one in db file?

Thanks a lot

Comment: How many versions can there be?

Comment: the report is generated every week. I am thinking to merge the historical data for 6 months therefore 6*4=24 versions

Comment: The default limit of [ATTACH](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html)ed databases is 10.